# Mail showing wrong submitted message

Tags: wordpress

I have setup a CF7 form with some CSS customization for theme as shown below:

```
<div class="chewy_pb_contact">
    <p class="clearfix">
        <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Your Name</label>
        [text* your-name id:your-name class:input class:et_pb_contact_name class:chewy_input placeholder "Name"]
    </p>
    <p class="clearfix">
        <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Your Email</label>
        [text* your-email id:your-email class:input class:et_pb_contact_email class:chewy_input placeholder "Email"]
    </p>
    <p class="clearfix">
        <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Mobile No.</label>
        [text* phone id:phone class:input class:et_pb_contact_name class:chewy_input placeholder "Mobile No."]
    </p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p class="clearfix chewy-question-label">
    <strong><label class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Question One: </label></strong>
    <p class="chewy-question">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
    [textarea* question-1 id:question-1 class:et_pb_contact_message class:input class:chewy_textarea placeholder "Answer Question One Here"]
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p class="clearfix chewy-question-label">
    <strong><label class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Question Two: </label></strong>
    <p class="chewy-question">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor?</p>
    [textarea* question-2 id:question-2 class:et_pb_contact_message class:input class:chewy_textarea placeholder "Answer Question Two Here"]
</p>
[submit class:chewy_pb_contact_submit "Submit"]
```

My mail's message body is:

```
From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Mobile: [phone]

Answer to Question One:
[question-1]

Answer to Question Two:
[question-2]
```

The problem is, in my mail, instead of the submitted text in [question-1] and [question-2] fields by the user, the paragraph texts written under the question 1 and question 2 labels are showing. Example:

> From: Example 
>   Mobile: 01770000000
>
> Answer to Question One:
>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor?
>
> Question Two:
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor?
>
> Answer to Question Two:
>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor?

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I've tested this exact form for you. All I can say is that I cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to compare the code on my test site vs the one on your site. I'll leave it there another while. https://testdrive.eco13.me/contact-form-test/